# Create txt file listing files in subfolders

Tags: php, javascript, linux, ubuntu

I have a directory that contains thousands of subfolders. I want to make it auto create a text file in each subfolder that will list all the files in that subfolder. I am running on Ubuntu 10.04 How can I do this in javascript or php?

Comment: I don't think you'd need PHP to do this, probably a way to do it natively in Ubuntu... http://askubuntu.com

Comment: This certainly isn't an ubuntu-related question.  Shell commands work the same way almost everywhere.  But Ruriko, can you clarify that you *really* need to do this in PHP, rather than using shell commands?  (You can't do it in Javascript, it (1) runs on the client or (2) doesn't have filesystem permissions.)

Comment: Why do you think PHP or JavaScript would be useful in solving your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In shell, it's a single command (albeit one that embeds other commands):

```
find /start/path -type d -exec sh -c "ls {} > {}/files.txt" \;
```

If you really need this in another language, please clarify your requirements.

Comment: @Ruriko If you need to do it from PHP, you can use one of the [execution functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) (I think I'd use `shell_exec()`).

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a JOB for php .. for Experimental Purpose you can use this :**

```
$di = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ( $di as $file ) {
    $name = $file->getPathInfo() . "/files.txt";
    touch($name);
    file_put_contents($name, $file->getFilename() . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

If you want to remove the text file you can always run

```
foreach ( $di as $file ) {
    $name = $file->getPathInfo() . "/files.txt";
    is_file($name) AND unlink($name);
}
```

Comment: +1.  Also nice.  One doesn't see `RecursiveIteratorIterator` used very often.  In fact, this is my first time.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its a sample php code which will create a file "files.txt" inside each directory and will put all the filenames in that folder ( will not add folder names).. Make sure you have write permission to all the folders

```
function recursive($directory)
{
    $dirs = array_diff(scandir($directory), Array( ".", ".." ));
    $dir_array = array();

    foreach($dirs as $d)
    {
        if(is_dir($directory."/".$d)){
            $dir_array[$d] = recursive($directory."/".$d);
        }
        else{
            $dir_array[$d] = $d;
            $fp = fopen("$directory/files.txt","a");
            fwrite($fp,"\n$d");
        }
    }
}   

recursive($start_directory);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by writing recursive PHP function using scandir.
For more help on PHP scandir, [check this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)